# Boundless Stored Proceedure Input

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, varchar

I'm passing a comma delimited list of ids to a stored procedure as a varchar(MAX). The problem is varchar caps at 8000 characters and the list could potentially be larger.

Is there a sql datatype where size doesn't matter? No pun intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar(MAX)` does not cap at 8000 characters. It's a replacement for the `text` data type (which is now deprecated). The `MAX` is not just a shortcut for a constant value of 8000; it actually indicates that the variable should be able to store an arbitrarily large amount of data.

If you're declaring a `varchar` variable without `MAX` as the qualifier, though, it will cap at 8000.

Answer (score 1):

No, varchar(MAX) is NOT limited to 8000 characters, so you'll be fine.